# Is it possible to prevent controller tests from being generated in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I've added the following to application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.controller_specs false
  g.test_framework :minitest, spec: false, fixture: false
end
```

However, controller tests continue to be generated when running `rails generate resource foo`

```
bundle exec rails generate resource foo
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20170912163219_create_foos.rb
      create    app/models/foo.rb
      invoke    minitest
      create      test/models/foo_test.rb
      invoke  controller
      create    app/controllers/foos_controller.rb
      invoke    minitest
      create      test/controllers/foos_controller_test.rb
      invoke  resource_route
       route    resources :foos
```

Am I missing something? Has the config API changed? Is this no longer possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (currently) a shortcoming of the Minitest-rails library, which ignores the `g.controller_specs false` configuration option.